# CSharpier in VSCode doesnt install

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use a C# formatter in my VSC IDE.

[image]
E.g. CSharpier.
I am using Ubuntu.
But instead that it works instantly it doesnt work when I press
shift+  ctrl+  I

Sometimes it just says:

[needs to be installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdlyp.png)
When I click it nothing happens.

Has anyone a idea?

Maybe this is important:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Disabled",
    "clangd.path": "/home/oem/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd/install/14.0.3/clangd_14.0.3/bin/clangd",
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "csharpier.csharpier-vscode",
    "[csharp]": {
        

        "editor.defaultFormatter": "csharpier.csharpier-vscode"
    },
    "csharp.inlayHints.parameters.enabled": true,
    "[cpp]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd"
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": 1
}
```

Format:

shift + strg + I

[image: shift strg I]

But I think it may has something to do with .NET..
I didn't install it.
I will try to install this .NET stuff again.

[image]
Thank you :D

Comment: What happens when you right click on your source, and choose "Format Document With..." ?  I am getting a possibility to "Configure Default Formatter "

Comment: BTW, you say: "it doesnt work when I press shift ctrl I"  On my system the "Format Document" is linked to SHIFT+ALT+F  (which is the default AFAIK)

Comment: yeah I think here it is shift strg and I ..

Comment: When doing right click in a CS file, I do get a longer menu (after setting the language to German), see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NRdx.png

Comment: Damn after around 10  times of restarting my pc and so VSC control + shift and I works somehow now... at least it worked right now when I select everything and do it.. I dont know exactly why!